# How to autohide v7 appbar when scrollin hides it partially - android

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, appbar, android-support-design

Following a [tutorial](http://blog.grafixartist.com/material-design-tabs-with-android-design-support-library/), I created this layout:

[image]

Here's my layout xml file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/tabanim_maincontent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabanim_appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tabanim_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabanim_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/tabanim_viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

What I want is that when I leave the scroll in the mid (when just lower part of App bar is visible), then the appbar should either **hide itself** or **show itself completely** like it happens in google play store:

[image]

Please note that in case of google play, the app bar is never half hidden when no finger is touching the screen

how to make the app bar like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the snap flag to the scroll flags:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap" />
```

This was just added in [Support Library v23.1.0](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/10/android-support-library-231.html).

Comment: thanks! it worked like charm! Is there also an option to set the acceleration of the snap?